# Unable to stop debug logging in log4J

Tags: java, logging, log4j, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I use log4j on a project that utilizes SpringAMQP to consume and write to a Rabbit pipe. Despite trying everything, I am unable to stop the debug logging on a couple of classes, specifically: Rabbittemplate and BlockingQueueconsumer

My log files are constantly flooded with these these couple of lines.

```
2014-10-09 11:19:20,914 DEBUG  RabbitTemplate - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,8)
2014-10-09 11:20:24,141 DEBUG  BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-BbFL7Ow0d_fL_aSaZgXMtg], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,6), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

This is what my Log4J configuration looks like now.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener=WARN|ERROR|FATAL
log4j.logger.org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener=WARN
```

I have tried everything in the Log4J configuration to turn off the debug logs on these dependencies but I haven't seen any difference in the logging. I use gradle to manage dependencies and builds and I have the Log4j.properties file in the src/main/resources folder. And it is dumped in the classpath when I build/run the project.

Can anyone help me turn off these logs so that I can keep the logs clean.

Comment: You have confirmed that your log4j configuration is definitely being used? e.g. you can change the logging level for other classes etc?

Comment: Good question Mark. I think the fact that my changes are not taking effect means that it probably isn't working. Editing my question and adding the relevant location etc.

Comment: Is the upper case L in Log4j.properties a typo? If not change it to lower case.

Comment: You can find out which configuration file is being used by adding `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to the jvm args.